# CakePHP with Bootstrap (from Twitter)

Tags: php, cakephp, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp-2.0

I am new to CakePHP and I want to know a way to use Boostrap from Twitter in layouts combined with cake.

My main concern is to make the Form Helper continues to function normally, because I think that it uses pre-configured CSS classes, and if I change the default css, I imagine that the Form Helper will stop to work as it should.

I read this tutorial but it doesn't seems to be complete.
[Build a PHP application using CakePHP and (twitter) Bootstrap, Part 1](http://stenbom.me/?p=9)

Has anyone done this?

Thank you! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All current answers require changes to the view files.

The following plugin will "Bootstrap-ify" your current views without any code/markup changes:

https://github.com/slywalker/TwitterBootstrap

All you need to do is [alias](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/new-features-in-cakephp-2-0.html#aliasing) the FormHelper and HtmlHelper so that all your existing calls to `$this->Form` & `$this->Html` will be handled by the plugin instead.

Can't get easier than that :)

Answer (score 13):

CSS is purely presentational; how can it affect the form helper from working as it should?

Some of the CSS validation classes might need reworking as well as what Cake returns when an error is encountered.

You can easily modify the output using the `error` option:

```
$this->Form->input('Model.field', array('error' => array('wrap' => 'span',
                                              'class' => 'boostrap-error')));
```

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1401/options-error

Comment: This is the point, the validation classes. The answer from XuDing is a perfect solution.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be what you are looking for.
https://github.com/loadsys/twitter-bootstrap-helper/branches

Answer (score 3):

I'm doing the same thing for an app, and I've found the CSS classes for form elements match up pretty well actually.

Twitter's Bootstrap form elements look like this:

```
<div class="clearfix">
  <label for="xlInput">X-Large input</label>
  <div class="input">
    <input class="xlarge" id="xlInput" name="xlInput" size="30" type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

And CakePHP's FormHelper generates elements like this:

```
<div class="input text">
    <label for="UserName">Name</label>
    <input name="data[User][name]" type="text" value="" id="UserName" />
</div>
```

The main difference being the label outside the div in Bootstrap. FormHelper lets you set custom classes like `array('class' => 'clearfix')`.

The `.input` class in Bootstrap is defined in *forms.less* and only sets `margin-left: 150px;` to move the inputs over to the right. If you don't use this style you can just add `margin-right: 20px;` to `<label>` instead.

The code in my form element ends up being:

```
echo $this->Form->input('first_name', array('div' => 'clearfix'));
```

...and generates elements that are styled properly by Bootstrap.

```
<div class="clearfix required">
  <label for="PersonFirstName">First Name</label>
  <input name="data[Person][first_name]" maxlength="50" type="text" id="PersonFirstName"/>
</div>
```

I'm still learning both frameworks so there may be problems with this. Hope it helps though.